# I want to redirect all the sub-folder pages to subdomain how do i do?

Tags: php, redirect, subdomain

I wanted to redirect all the pages in a subfolder having a page link like `(https:///www.domain.com/amp/page-name)` to a subdomain having a page link like `(https:///m.domain.com/page-name)`.

How should I redirect the all pages respective of the subdomain page?

Do I need to add redirection code for each page single page or is there in option so that I can redirect it in a single code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the .htaccess file in the root directory of your webiste.com site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if not already blog.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.website\.com$ [NC] 
#if request is for blog/, go to blog.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.website.com [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit .htaccess file and add new line

```
        Redirect /amp/page-name https:///m.domain.com/page-name
```

Comment: I want to redirect all the pages included in the subfolder to the domain this code will work for only one page